# How to get the currently playing audio as audio input in Processing?

Tags: audio, input, processing, minim

I am creating a simple audio visualizer. Here is the code

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioInput in;
FFT fft;

int w;

PImage fade;

void setup() {
  size(640,480); // draw screen
  minim = new Minim(this); // new minim object

  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO,512); // audio input from microphone (have to change this to get currently playing audio)

  fft = new FFT(in.bufferSize(),in.sampleRate()); // new fft object

  fft.logAverages(60,7);

  stroke(255); 
  w=width/fft.avgSize();
  strokeWeight(w); // display lines as bars

  background(0);

}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fft.forward(in.mix); //generate fourier series

  for(int i = 0; i < fft.avgSize(); i++) {
    line((i*w)+(w/2),height, (i*w)+(w/2), height - fft.getAvg(i)*4); // draw bars
  }
}
```

Here `in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO,512);`  gives the audio input from the from the microphone. But I need to get currently playing audio *(What you hear from the speaker or headphone)* of the computer and visualize it.

If there is any method or any other way to get currently playing audio as the input please mention. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like this are best answered by reading [the reference](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audioinput_class_audioinput.html):

> An AudioInput is a connection to the current record source of the computer. How the record source for a computer is set will depend on the soundcard and OS, but typically a user can open a control panel and set the source from there. Unfortunately, there is no way to set the record source from Java.

In other words, this is a setting that the user has to change in their control panel. This seems to be confirmed [here](https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1229300351.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588279/processing-getting-the-volume-of-a-playing-sound-file-in-processing).